# Prism Xamarin Forms - Slow loading of pages

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism

I am having issues when calling NavigationService.Navigate, it navigates instantly, but content is not rendered yet as there is too many elements. You can interact with them, but you cant see them, until few seconds later (5 secs sometimes even) it loads fully and renders.
Is there any way to preload this "graphics" in Prism?
Can I call anything at start of application, make start longer, and make pages render instantly?
I am using Prism and Xamarin Forms with Android.

I tried Xamarin Fast Renderer, did not help. Our app is simply complicated, and whats worse, it has 0 XAML and only code behind as for element rendering. This was inherited from previous company which was developing it originally. Any help will be welcomed.

Comment: xamarin forms has always been slow, if you don't benefit from the cross platform capabilities, better use xamarin android (or net6.0-android / net7.0-android now)

Answer (score 1):

How much elements are too many elements? I have pages with 2000+ xaml lines rendering instantly. Without code is hard to tell. Few things you can take a closer look:

1. Async calls. Double check you are not awaiting for processes to end before rendering your page.
2. UI thread work. Main thread should only be used for the application interaction. Do as much work in background as you can. Since you are using Prism, ViewModel bindings are your friends to update UI once the background work is done.
3. If you really need to use UI thread, you should consider things like Shimmer or ActivityIndicator